# empty DB joincolumn after cascade insert in bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 2 classes that are connected by a bidirectional ManyToOne / OneToMany relationship:

Member in ClassA:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "classA")
private List<ClassB> classBList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
```

Member in ClassB:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CLASSA_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ClassA classA;
```

When I call **classA.getClassBList().add(newClassB);** a new DB entry for classB is created, but the DB column CLASSA_ID remains null.
of course all entities are defined in persistence.xml.

i appreciate any help, maybe it's just a little detail.

---

Thanks to ***bigGuy*** 
My class looks like that now:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "CLASSA_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<ClassB> classBList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();


@ManyToOne
private ClassA classA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation *@JoinColumn* indicates that this entity is the owner of the relationship.

In your case, owner is ClassB.

So, you should use this line to create relationship:

```
newClassB.setClassA(classA);
```

If you want to create relationships with line

```
classA.getClassBList().add(newClassB);
```

make ClassA owner of relationship (move *@JoinColumn* to classA).